# Async Get Request return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, get

I have the code:

```
if (venue_exists(instagramUserID)){
    alert('A');
}else {                              
    alert('C');
}  


function venue_exists(instagramUserID) {    
    $.get( "/venues/" + instagramUserID, function(json) {
        if (json.data.success){
            alert('B');            
            return true;
        }         
 }, "json" );
```

Currently my output is: `B`, `C`

I'm confused as to why the code is not going into `A` as `true` is being returned. Does this have something to do with the `asynchronous request`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because $.get is **asynchronous** - the return value of venue_exists is `undefined` ... which is `falsey` - and I'm surprised your alerts don't come C then B ... NOTE: never use alert for debugging code, especially asynchronous code, it screws up what you think is happening

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it happens because ajax is asynchronous. When you call venue_exists it returns undefined. 
If you need to have that check you need to call it synchronously.

```
function venue_exists(instagramUserID) {
   return JSON.parse($.ajax({
     url: '/venues/' + instagramUserID,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     async: false
}).responseText);}
```